# Rails 5 - convert integers from db into written-out months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a block of ruby code that's printing my month_published column in my view.

```
<% @publications.each do |publication| %>
    <p><%= publication.month_published %></p>
<% end %>
```

All of these values are stored as integers: 01 for January, 02 for February, etc., so that's what it's printing. 
How do I get my code to write out the months as words instead of integers?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use I18n to accomplish this:

```
I18n.t('date.month_names')[01]
```

This should work out of the box for `en` but if you want another language you'll need to add

```
fr:
  date:
    month_names:
    -
    - janvier
    - février
    - mars
    - avril
    - mai
    - juin
    - juillet
    - août
    - septembre
    - octobre
    - novembre
    - décembre
```

As an example to your locale file (translations quickly grabbed from the [local/fr.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml) of the [rails-i18n](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the constant `Date::MONTHNAMES`, it is defined by [Rails](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) like this:

```
[nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

So in your view you has to do something like this:

```
<% @publications.each do |publication| %>
    <p><%= Date::MONTHNAMES[publication.month_published] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using

`strftime('%B')`

In your case,

`<%= publication.month_published.strftime('%B') %>`

should work well.

The `(%B)` argument converts to the full month name.  See [THIS](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) link for other directives that you can use with `strftime`.